# Добавить в компонент react свой js

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Компонент react

```
class Header extends React.PureComponent {
render() {
    const {location, base, mainSearchType, navigationItems, CurrentUserComponent, currentLocation, setLocation} = this.props;

    const searchType = location.pathname.indexOf('companies') !== -1
        ? 'companies'
        : mainSearchType;

    const searchRouteName = base
        ? `${base}.${searchType}.index`
        : `${searchType}.index`;

    let searchPrompt;

    switch (searchType) {
        case `vacancies`:
            searchPrompt = ``;
            break;

        case `resumes`:
            searchPrompt = ``;
            break;

        case `companies`:
            searchPrompt = ``;
            break;

        default:
            searchPrompt = ``;
            break;
    }

    return (
        <header className="header">
            <nav className="header-row">
                <div className="header-row__content">
                    <div id="menu-toggle" className="menu-icon">
                    <div className="menu-icon-line"></div>
                    </div>
                        <div id="mobile-nav" className="mobile-nav">
                            <div className="menu-mobile">
                                <div id="menu-right_close" className="menu-icon-line_right_close"></div>
                                <span className="menu-mobile__title">Меню</span>
                            </div>
                        </div>
```

Свой скрипт js

```
    const menuToggle = document.querySelector('#menu-toggle');
    const mobileNavContainer = document.querySelector('#mobile-nav');
        menuToggle.onclick = function(){
        menuToggle.classList.toggle('menu-icon-active');
        mobileNavContainer.classList.toggle('mobile-nav--active');
    }
```

Как вставить\подключить свой js к данному компоненту react что бы скрипт нормально работал?!

Comment: Так подключать скрипты не надо. Лучше работайте в реакте, как надо работать в реакте. Почитайте примеры, документацию. Например https://learn-reactjs.ru/tutorial

Comment: Кладете свой скрипт в отдельный файл, раз уж на то пошло, оборачиваете его в функцию, затем эту функцию экспортируете из файла, в своем компоненте делаете импорт той самой функции и вызываете ее там, где нужно, я так подозреваю в `componentDidMount` лучше, после монтирования.

Answer (score 0):

Подключить его так же как и остальные файлы \ компоненты.

```
import myOwnScript from './myOwnScript.js'; /как пример
```